# Submit multiple tabs within one view ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, tabs

I have an ASP .NET application with multiple tabs on a view, each tab containing several inputs for each course attendee (name, phone number, job title, etc).

I created a jquery function to collect data from views and generate the JSON accordingly:

```
 function getAttendees() {
            var sections = [];

            $(".divWithInputs").each(function (i, val) {
                var tab = $(val).serializeArray();
                sections.push(tab);
            });

            return sections;
        }
```

And the submit function:

```
$("#checkoutAttendees").click(function () {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("Attendees", JSON.stringify(getAttendees()));

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/controllerURL",
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                });
            });
```

I have an issue when reading the JSON, because I need an IEnumerable of Attendee objects to populate with this sort of data:

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "name":"first-name-attendee-0",
         "value":"Jon"
      },
      {  
         "name":"last-name-attendee-0",
         "value":"Stark"
      },
      {  
         "name":"email-attendee-0",
         "value":"jon.stark@northwall.com"
      },
      {  
         "name":"phone-attendee-0",
         "value":"0181042981029840"
      },
      {  
         "name":"company-attendee-0",
         "value":"Nightwatch"
      },
      {  
         "name":"job-title-attendee-0",
         "value":"King"
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "name":"first-name-attendee-1",
         "value":"Aria"
      },
      {  
         "name":"last-name-attendee-1",
         "value":"Stark"
      },
      {  
         "name":"email-attendee-1",
         "value":"noemail@nodomain.com"
      },
      {  
         "name":"phone-attendee-1",
         "value":"000000000000000"
      },
      {  
         "name":"company-attendee-1",
         "value":"No organization"
      },
      {  
         "name":"job-title-attendee-1",
         "value":"Killer"
      }
   ],
   [  
      {  
         "name":"first-name-attendee-2",
         "value":"Mad"
      },
      {  
         "name":"last-name-attendee-2",
         "value":"King"
      },
      {  
         "name":"email-attendee-2",
         "value":"mad.king@yahoo.com"
      },
      {  
         "name":"phone-attendee-2",
         "value":"019209840921840219"
      },
      {  
         "name":"company-attendee-2",
         "value":"Kingdom"
      },
      {  
         "name":"job-title-attendee-2",
         "value":"King"
      }
   ]
]
```

Any advise on how to properly transform data from JSON into  a list of Attendees ?

Thank you.

Comment: look at using Newtonsoft https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: Assuming I understood your question/post, look into how you're creating your data `getAttendees`. Additionally, sort of unclear why you needed to do that - _assuming_ the front end is a _single_ form, the _display_ of which is just "tabified". In other words, why do you need to recreate the form data?

Comment: There is a form for the person who books the course and for each course attendant will be a tab with some fields within a div. When submitting the form, each course attendee will be part of an array, which translates to a collection in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: in backend I had to create a list of lists of NameValuePair

The Action method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TrainingBook(FormCollection formCollection)
        var viewModel = new TrainingFormViewModel();

        var attendeesListJSON = formCollection["Attendees"];

        var attendeesJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>(attendeesListJSON);

        List<Attendees> attendees = new List<Attendees>();

        foreach (var item in attendeesJson)
        {
            attendees.Add(new Attendees {
                FirstName = item[0].Value,
                LastName = item[1].Value,
                WorkEmailAddress = item[2].Value,
                PhoneNumber = item[3].Value,
                Organization = item[4].Value,
                JobTitle = item[5].Value
            });
        }
```

A key value pair is name and value for an input, the first list of key value pairs is one attendee, the the list of lists, ofc, all the attendees.